# Javascript data management

Tags: javascript, jaydata

Which of the following data management for javascript is recommended?

1. [jLinq](http://hugoware.net/Projects/jLinq)
2. [jOrder](http://jorder.net/)

I am familiar with jLinq but not sure weather to use jLinq or jOrder. Would prefer the one with a better API.

Answer (score 1):

jLinq is not very efficient, but it is "nice" to deal with arrays of JSON data (which is its primary goal anyways).
jOrder is more like a client-side database implementation, and it uses keys and indexes for best performance.

But for querying data, there are even more options, such as [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) - and depending on the rest of your ecosystem some may fit better than others (for instance, if you use some JS framework shich supports observable collections, you might want to use a solution that can hook into those efficiently).

Answer (score 0):

Give [JayData](http://jaydata.org) a try! It provides JavaScript Language Query (a feature much like LINQ, where you can use JavaScript's native syntax to query data over the network) and crud operations toward a growing number of data providers.

Answer (score -2):

You could also use localStorage - very easy. (no API)